# Failed to start Restful service with cxf spring in osgi container

Tags: java, spring, maven, osgi, cxf

I have created a Restful service with Maven, CXF and spring. For Maven archetype, I choose quickstart. Here is the pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.example.ExampleBean</groupId>
<artifactId>RestExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

class:

```
package com.example.ExampleBean;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/example")
public class RestExample {
@GET
    @Path("/")
    public String ping() throws Exception {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/bundle-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http-jetty.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>


<bean id="exampleBean" class="com.example.ExampleBean.RestExample" />

<jaxrs:server id="exampleService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="exampleBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

maven install is successful. When I deploy the bundle to Fuse ESB karaf OSGi container and start it, I got:

[ 286] [Active     ] [            ] [Failed ] [   60] RestExample (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)

It failed to start. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There's no other information or logs at startup?

Comment: No. I didnt see any other information or log